# Making a consumer as an inner class in the serviceImpl

Tags: java, spring, events

I have a problem scanning the consumer that I made as an inner class inside my serviceimpl.java

code below:

```
public class CredsServiceImpl implements CredsService {
@Service
public static class userCredsConsumer implements Consumer<Event<UserData>> {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(userCredsConsumer.class);

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    CredsDAO credsDAO;

    public void accept(Event<UserData> notificationDataEvent) {
        UserData notificationData = notificationDataEvent.getData();
        entityManager.setEntityId(notificationData.getTenantId());
        List<CredsDTO> credsUser = credsDAO.selectByUserId(notificationData.getUserId());
        if(credsUser == null || credsUser.isEmpty()){
            log.info("No Existing Credential Watcher Record for User [{}]", notificationData.getUserName());
        }else{
            credsDAO.deleteByUserId(notificationData.getUserId());
            log.info("Creds Record for User [{}] is Deleted", notificationData.getUserName());
        }
    }  
}
```

}

and I am trying to access it from the credentialconfig that I made

```
@Autowired
private EventBus eventBus;

@Autowired
UserCredsConsumer userCredsConsumer;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    eventBus.on($("userCredsConsumer"), userCredsConsumer);
}
```

the problem I have right now is it is not going the the userCredsConsumer class that I made in the serviceimpl.

any insights would help.. if I don't make it as an inner class it is working fine. but if I make it as an inner class its not working properly.. but I really need this to be in an inner class for specific reasons in the business.

Comment: Guess you need @Service on CredsServiceImpl aswell

Comment: It's working correct now.. Thanks!